# Nifi || Combining flowfiles coming from multiple Putsql processor and connect with other process group

Tags: apache-nifi

Nifi || Combining flowfiles coming from multiple Putsql processor and connect with other process group.

We are doing calculation in two ways:

- First Process group - Inserting data into table.
- Second Process group - Doing calculation on inserted data.

I want to connect both the flows so in case of any issue no overall calculation should take place and they both run in one go. Currently I am scheduling them separately.

I tried mergecontent but nothing works.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The 'Success' relationship from the PutSQL contains records that were successfully updated in the database.

Add an 'Input Port' to your 'Overall Calculation' group, and drag the 'Success' relationship from each PutSQL on to the 'Overall Calculation' and connect to the same 'Input Port'.

[image: flow]

Answer (score 0):

I have used Mergecontent with replacetext processor and it  worked.
Thanks everyone